# How do I keep an error handler from activating multiple times?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I recently implemented error handlers for a cooldown embed. I've pasted it onto all of my configs (6) and ran the bot, but whenever I tried to run the cooldown, it sent it 6 times. Is there any way to keep the error per config or should I just add it onto every command separately?

**main.py**

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        em = discord.Embed(title=":x: Not so fast...", description="Please try again in {:.2f}s".format(error.retry_after), color=0xfffafa)
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
    else:
        raise error
```

**all other cogs**

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
            em = discord.Embed(title=":x: Not so fast...", description="Please try again in {:.2f}s".format(error.retry_after), color=0xfffafa)
            await ctx.send(embed=em)
        else:
            raise error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, a better solution is to add them to the command specifically, this also means it can help diagnose an issue with a command more exact.

You can also add any error events to the specific listener, just like how you done it for all commands, instead add them individually.

```
@bot.command()
async def command_name(ctx):
    # ...


@command_name.error 
async def command_name_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        await ctx.send("An error you think your command could throw" + error)
```

`@command_name.error` put your command name before the .error, then this makes an error listener for that command, if it produces an error.

Comment: that's what I was going to do if I didn't find a different solution